# How to exclude plug-in that does not support browser from browser build

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use [cordova-plugin-device-name](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-device-name), but when testing in browser I get “[ERROR] Error initializing Cordova: Missing Command Error”. In the console I get “Error: exec proxy not found for :: DeviceName :: get”. After looking at plugin.xml I can see that it has no support for the browser platform. Is there any way to exclude this plug-in from browser when I add the plug-in to my project? Currently I have Android, iOS, and browser as my supported platforms.

I am hoping to use the cordova add plugin mechanic and not [plugman](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/plugman.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Apache's [Device Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device#devicemodel) instead of the one you're using now. The Device Plugin supports the `browser` platform as well as many others.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady () {
    alert(device.model);
}
```

If you want to continue using the `cordoba-plugin-device-name` then maybe look try detecting if you're on a browser and avoid using the `DeviceName` object.

```
if(device.platform === 'browser'){

}else{
    /* do stuff with DeviceName */
}
```

Comment: I am using the Device Plugin for other data, but I need the device name (Bluetooth name on Android. iTunes name on iOS). Is there no way to config Cordova to not include a plugin on a non supported platform?

Comment: see my updates above. Only way i think you could do that is to remove the entry in `plugins/<platform>.json`.